# Install SQL Server on Mac

Tags: sql-server, docker

I am on the following page:

https://www.quackit.com/sql_server/mac/install_sql_server_on_a_mac.cfm

In step 1, it says to use the following Docker command in a terminal:

```
docker pull microsoft/mssql-server-linux
```

However, that command is outdated and did not work.

I made my way to the following URL:

https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-mssql-server

I used the following command I found there:

```
docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
```

Using the command directly above, I could see the terminal pulling and completing the installation.

So now in step 2, it says to use the following Docker command:

```
docker run -d --name Homer -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e 'SA_PASSWORD=myPassw0rd' -p 1433:1433 microsoft/mssql-server-linux
```

But then says if I used a different container, I have to replace "microsoft/mssql-server-linux" with my container image.

This is where I'm stuck.

I tried to use the following:

```
docker run -d --name Homer -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e 'SA_PASSWORD=myPassw0rd' -p 1433:1433 mcr.microsoft.com/mssql
```

But I get the following error:

> Unable to find image 'mcr.microsoft.com/mssql:latest' locally
> docker: Error response from daemon: manifest for mcr.microsoft.com/mssql:latest not found: manifest unknown: manifest tagged by "latest" is not found.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pulled the image, you used:

```
mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
```

When you ran the container, you used something else:

```
docker run -d ... mcr.microsoft.com/mssql
```

Why did you shorten this and leave stuff out of it? Docker can't read your mind or perform auto-complete for you. Try:

```
docker run -d ... mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
```

Comment: You can verify using `docker ps` - also I'm surprised that password passed complexity checks (hopefully you just dumbed it down for us).

Comment: Using docker ps, I can see a container name "Homer", just as executed in the command.  I did indeed dumb down the password.  Thank you so much for your help.